# How to automatically update an entity when an entity is persisted or updated

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I have an entity that has a reference to another one like these:

```
class School {
   private boolean used = false;
}

class Student {
   @ManyToOne
   private School school;
}
```

The attribute `used` indicates that the `School` entity is whether used, referenced or not. So when created, a `School` entity should have `used` false, but once a `Student` makes a reference to it, the `used` must be turned to true. Is there any automatically way to do this like triggers in database?

I try to use `@PrePersist` and `@PostPersist` on `Student` entity like this but it doesn't work:

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist(){
    school.setUsed(true);
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought is that School should also have a reverse list of students. i.e.

```
class School {
   private List<Student> students;
}
```

So when the school is loaded, you can easily access the list of students. Then finding out if a school is being used becomes very simple. You will not longer need a boolean flag, just this:

```
public boolean hasStudents() {
    return students.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: It's the simplest and smartest solution for my case, thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to write a trigger on the insert, update of Student table, which will check if someone is holding the foreign key reference to school and you will have to check for all schools here. Also map your used variable to a column in School table. If any student is holding a reference, than make the column true and call a refresh from your application layer.

On the second thought, check if this is possible. When ever you need the logic for used variable, see that if you can write an HQL and using that HQL check if that particular school is currently getting used by any of the Student. This I think is a cleaner approach, but finally it's a call based on requirements :)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you need to define the **CascadeType**. 
See the example below:

```
class Team {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  Set players;
} 
class Player {
  @ManyToOne
  Team team;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the remind, but it's not the point here bro. It's only for when you persist/update/remove a player, it persists/updates/removes the team as well.